# Is this mySQL trigger syntax correct?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Please help me out. I'm inserting a String into a column in a mysql db table. but since I'm using a predefined API to insert into the table I need a *Trigger* to help parse the string into the rest of the columns.

the String coming in looks like this:  *((admin)) [[clientId]] >>>Update client Profile*

that String will be inserted into the column 'Message'. but there are 3 other columns in that table I want to insert to: user_id, client_id & action. so I need to parse the message into 3 different strings in order to put them in the correct column.

This is what I have, Is this correct???

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'parse_log4j_message' BEFORE INSERT ON 'util_audit' 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   
select NEW.MESSAGE into @message; //adding String into this variable
    select LEFT(message, 1) from table into @firstChar; //get first Char in Message
IF strcmp(@firstChar,'(') = 0 THEN  //if first char is '(', then message is correct
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@message, ')', 2) into @userId; //-> admin
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@message, ']', 2) into @tempClientId;  
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@message, '[', -1) into @clientId; //-> clientId
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@message, '>', -1) into @action; //-> the rest of the message
    SET NEW.USER_ID = @userId;  // set into the columns of the table
    SET NEW.CLIENT_ID = @clientId;
    SET NEW.ACTION = @action; 
END IF; 
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this parsing script firstly -

```
SET @message = '((admin)) [[clientId]] >>>Update client Profile';

SET @userId = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@message, '))', 1), '((', -1);
SET @clientId = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@message, ']]', 1), '[[', -1);
SET @action = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@message, '>>>', -1);

SELECT @userId, @clientId, @action;

+---------+-----------+-----------------------+
| @userId | @clientId | @action               |
+---------+-----------+-----------------------+
| admin   | clientId  | Update client Profile |
+---------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

If this is correct, then add this solution to your trigger.